# how to redirect http to https in apache server by using solaris

Tags: apache, http, unix, https, solaris

Can someone help how to direct HTTP to HTTPS? and Am having an SSL certificate on my Solaris(UNIX) server.

this is my initial server name `HTTP://rsdev.mt.att.com:8001/` once we entering it is going through this URL `https://rsdev.mt.att.com:8801/cgi-bin/bounce?http://rsdev.mt.att.com:8001/cgi-bin/esprMgr`
don't know what is happening here.
But I want my URL to be secure.

Please help me to resolve.

Comment: "don't know what is happening here" - please show your current rules that are triggering this seemingly "malformed" redirect. And where exactly are you putting these directives?

Comment: @MrWhite, inside http.conf file is having this is server name rsdev.mt.att.com:8801

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant config. Presumably you have separate virtual hosts defined for the two ports (HTTP and HTTPS)? And the redirect directives are inside the relevant vHost container? But are these requests being proxied to a backend CGI script? OR do you have a separate server entirely just for HTTPS?!

Comment: @MrWhite no we don't have separate VM's

Comment: virtual hosts is not VM. You may start an Apache from scratch to have a basic understanding of Apache.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.